# Проблема при обновлении записи с виджетом FileInput от kartik

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте, использую виджет [FileInput](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput)  для загрузки миниатюр к записи.
Создание/редактирование/etc записи сделано при помощи CRUD.

Дело в том, что когда происходит подгрузка формы обновления записи - не подгружается название изображения в БД, в отличии от других полей.

[image: Демонстрация отсуствия url]

Допустим, изображение и все другие поля заполнены и мы решили отредактировать поле `blocks`.

1. Заходим в редактирование записи.
2. Заменяем содержимое поле `blocks`.
3. Сохраняем.

Поскольку, поле миниатюры пустое -- сохранится null заместо текущего содержимого.

Собственно, хочу решить данную проблему. Пока из вариантов сделать отдельную функцию для обновления/добавления/удаления миниатюры, но это уже крайний вариант. Думаю, кто либо-встречался с данной проблемой и надеюсь, что сможет мне помочь.

Вот часть кода, которая отвечает за вывод формы загрузки изображения:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'miniature')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]); ?>
```

Функция сохранения изображения в модели:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($file =  UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'miniature') ){

        $dir = Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/web/upload/';
        $this->miniature = time().'.'.$file->extension;
        $file->saveAs($dir.$this->miniature);

    }

    return parent::beforeSave($insert); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно сделать проверку пустое ли значение или нет.

Если не пустое, то заполнить новые данные старым значением. Конечно же при условии, что нового значения Вы не передали.
Код:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
   if(!$this->isNewRecord && self::getOldAttribute('miniature') != ''){
        $this->miniature = self::getOldAttribute('miniature');
   }
    return parent::beforeSave($insert); 
}else{
// Код сохранения нового изображения
}
```

*Решение via **slo_nik**.*